# Key Error when trying to run code. Panda Juypter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run my code but no matter what I try I keep getting a Key error KeyError: 'control_percent' .
Here's my code

```
df["map_type"] = np.where(df["control_percent"] == NaN, "escort","control")
df.loc[df["map_type"]== "control",["time_banked","payload_distance"]]=np.NaN
df["round_start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["round_start_time"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df["round_end_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["round_end_time"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df["year"] = df["round_start_time"].dt.year


I tried switching the (df["control_percent"] with (some_digit = X.loc["control_percent"].array
and (df.loc["control_percent"]
```

Comment: A key error is indicating that the key is not present in the dict/dataframe. You'll want to check your column headers to see if there is one called "control_percent".

Comment: Yes I was able to figure it out thank you